# dconf usage in shell scripts for GVariant

Tags: scripts

I get an error when using "dconf write" to value a key with a [] list from a bash shell script

The script below works as expected :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "dconf write <PATH> \"['val1','val2']\""
dconf write <PATH> "['val1','val2']"
dconf read <PATH>
echo OK
```

The script below fails with "error: 0-9:unterminated string constant"

```
#!/bin/bash
list="\"['val1','val2']\""
echo dconf write <PATH> $list
dconf write <PATH> $list                #fail
dconf read <PATH>
echo NOK
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

The OP posted a solution in his question:

1st solution:

```
dconf write <PATH> "$list"              #ok
```

2nd solution:

```
eval dconf write <PATH> $list           #ok
```